# Running and exiting PyQt application multiple times

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, pyqt, pyqt5

### The context

I am creating my own version of the board game [Battleship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_(game)) using PyQt. A PyQt main window contains both own and enemy boards. Boards are made up of clickable tiles that players 'fire at'. The implementation supports HUMANvsAI and AIvsAI games. I would like to test the strength of my AI algorithms through simulation. For example, I would like to run in a loop 1,000 AIvsAI games and get stats on % victory, average accuracy, etc. [image: Screenshot of the game]

### The main issue

I am struggling to run the PyQt app multiple times to gather game data, e.g. in a for loop. Specifically, I cannot find a way to run the application, exit it, and re-run it again. Conceptually speaking I am looking for something like this:

> ```
> # conceptual snippet
>   for i in range(n):
>     app = QApplication([])
>     window = MainWindow(b_size, boat_dict, players)
>     app.exec_()
> ```

With the call to exit the app somewhere else and called each time the game is over:

> ```
> # conceptual snippet
>   if is_game_over():
>     sys.exit(app.exec_())
> ```

But this simple solution breaks the for loop. Any feedback would be welcome on how to run and exit a PyQt application multiple times, either sequentially (e.g. for loop approach) or in parallel threads.

Comment: If you want to see the AI vs AI results, why even have the overhead of spawning a Qt App at all? Why not just isolate the AI game logic and observe that? The only reason I imagine it would be worth the resources to generate a GUI like this is to be able to have human interaction.

Comment: @JoeHabel Currently the logic is intertwined with PyQt objects. For example, it is the class 'tile' that stores its own game data on whether it's been hit already/has a boat/boat is hit/boat is sunk etc. I agree that it would be possible to use a list of lists / numpy array as a board and test the AI separately, but this comes at the expense of re-creating the game logic without PyQt. I'd be interested to avoid this

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `sys.exit()` since that instruction serves to terminate the execution of the program, if you want to terminate the Qt application you must use `QCoreApplication::quit()` (or `QCoreApplication::exit(0)`). In addition, another improvement would be to use multiprocessing:

```py
import random
from multiprocessing import Pool

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


def create_app(i):
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    w = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle("Game-{}".format(i))
    w.show()

    # emulate end-game
    def end_game():
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit()

    timeout = random.randint(1000, 2000)  # 1000-2000 milliseconds
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(timeout, end_game)
    app.exec_()

    # emulate results
    o = {"victory": random.randint(0, 101), "average": random.randint(0, 101)}
    return o


def main():
    results = []
    pool = Pool(processes=8)
    for i in range(1000):
        r = pool.apply_async(create_app, args=(i,))
        results.append(r)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print([result.get() for result in results])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Just a couple of notes on using multiprocessing, if you're using Windows, which based on your screenshot looks like the case, you might need to make use of multiprocessing's freeze_support (I know I had to back when I was using Windows, but it's been a while, so I'm not sure what's changed). This is as simple as adding the following import `from multiprocessing import freeze_support`, and then above the `main()` call, adding a `freeze_support()` call. Also note, that the number of processes in the `Pool(processes=8)`, depends on your available cpu cores.

Comment: @JoeHabel Thanks for the information, mmm, the screenshot is not mine (I hate Windows, I am Linux lover), on the other hand my answer does not try to explain the limitations of the implementation of multiprocessing in each OS, it is only an attempt of a basic approach because if I wanted to do what seems like you are trying to get a problem: the small space provided by SO is not suitable for this unless a precise question is asked.

Comment: @JoeHabel  I know the points that you point out but my little explanation of the limitations is intentional for the OP to investigate. I think the comment you should point to the OP.

Comment: You're right, that comment wasn't meant to be directed towards you but rather @AverageBoy. I just saw the OP's Windows screenshot, and had flashbacks to the horrors of Windows and multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

I've to tell you, your question is dangerously near the level of a "too-broad" flag. The real problem is: how do you want to keep track of the gathered data, and what do you want to do with that data? This question may have *a lot* of answers.

As you already found out, you can't use `sys.exit`, but you could gather your data in different ways.
If you're going to run your application within a controlled environment, a possible solution is to serialize your gathered data while controlling the whole "gathering" process from the application

Semi-pseudo-code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import json

class BattleShipWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    restart = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    # ...

    def storeData(self, data):
        # get the app data location
        appDir = QtWidgets.QStandardPath.standardLocations(
            QtCore.QStandardaPaths.AppDataLocation)[0]
        # if it doesn't exists, create it
        if not QtCore.QFile.exists(appDir):
            QtCore.QDir().mkpath(appDir)
        now = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime()
        fileName = str(now.toMSecsSinceEpoch() // 1000)
        # write down the data
        with open(os.path.join(appDir, fileName), 'w') as df:
            df.write(json.dumps(data))

    def getGameData(self):
        # gather your own data here, this is just an example
        return {'gameData': [1, 2, 3]}

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(
            self, 'Play again?',
            'Play another game?', 
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes|QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No
            ) == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
                self.storeData(self.getGameData())
                self.restart.emit()


class BattleShipApp(QtWidgets.QApplication):
    def restart(self):
        self.currentGame = BattleShipWindow()
        self.currentGame.restart.connect(self.restart)
        self.currentGame.show()

    def exec_(self):
        self.currentGame = BattleShipWindow()
        self.currentGame.restart.connect(self.restart)
        self.currentGame.show()
        super(BattleShipApp, self).exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = BattleShipApp(sys.argv)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note: this is a [semi]pseudo code, I obviously didn't test it. Its purpose is to show how it could behave, so don't expect it to work as it is.